# Free option for virtual SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on an application in my free time and I want to use a SQL Server database. I have the .iso for SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer but I don't have an extra computer to dedicate as a server. I assumed I could use VMware Player for a virtual server but from what I've read it seems that I would need VMware vCenter or another paid version.

Is there a free option for creating a SQL Server database virtually? This will be extremely small scale (3 tables and just for my personal use) so I am not worried about performance at all.

Comment: Why not just run SQL Server on your personal development system? You don't need a separate system for SQL Server. It's very quiet and low-impact if it's not being used hard.

Comment: Don't be thrown by the .iso. It's not an OS install - it's just a disk image containing a standard Windows installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install that locally on your computer. There is no need for a virtual engine. Even if some of the MS documents say you need a server operating system, that is not the case. The setup has a check for valid operating system, and it just installs fine on Windows XP, Vista, 7 in my experience.

But if you want, VMWare Player would also work. In contrast to its name, you can also create virtual engines with it - but with some limitations.

And for a really small solution, even SQL Server Express, which is also free, would do. If I remeber correctly, the main restriction is that the data may not exceed 1 TB.

Comment: Info on max SQL Express DB size here: [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Database Size Limit Increased to 10GB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2010/04/21/database-size-limit-increased-to-10gb-in-sql-server-2008-r2-express.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can run locally without any problems, even in your dev/gaming/browsing computer without creating too much interference. There is no problem in installing it for testing and even for production of small systems (the express edition is free and valid for those uses).

Another, even slimmer, alternative, if you dare to upgrade to SQL 2012, would be to use a new feature called LocalDB. It's basically the very same db engine with a very important difference: it does **NOT** run as a service, but instead it's a regular program that is automatically started when a connection is attempted. Advantages would be that it does not consume resources until it's needed and yet you've got almost the full feature set of the real server. [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh510202.aspx) is an introduction on it. While I've never used it (always with the full express version), it seems good for the kind of programs you want to develop.